# Calculating Weighted Average with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, weighted-average

My goal is to get a weighted average from one table, based on another tables primary key.

Example Data:

Table1

```
Key     WEIGHTED_AVERAGE

0200    0
```

Table2

```
ForeignKey    Length    Value
0200          105       52
0200          105       60
0200          105       54
0200          105       -1
0200          47        55
```

I need to get a weighted average based on the length of a segment and I need to ignore values of -1. I know how to do this in SQL, but my goal is to do this in LINQ. It looks something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT Sum(t2.Value*t2.Length)/Sum(t2.Length) AS WEIGHTED_AVERAGE
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t2.Value <> -1
AND t2.ForeignKey = t1.Key;
```

I am still pretty new to LINQ, and having a hard time figuring out how I would translate this.  The result weighted average should come out to roughly 55.3. Thank you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's an extension method for LINQ.

```
public static double WeightedAverage<T>(this IEnumerable<T> records, Func<T, double> value, Func<T, double> weight)
{
    if(records == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(records), $"{nameof(records)} is null.");

    int count = 0;
    double valueSum = 0;
    double weightSum = 0;

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        count++;
        double recordWeight = weight(record);

        valueSum += value(record) * recordWeight;
        weightSum += recordWeight;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(records)} is empty.");

    if (count == 1)
        return value(records.Single());

    if (weightSum != 0)
        return valueSum / weightSum;
    else
        throw new DivideByZeroException($"Division of {valueSum} by zero.");
}
```

This has become extremely handy because I can get a weighted average of any group of data based on another field within the same record.

**Update**

I now check for dividing by zero and throw a more detailed exception instead of returning 0. Allows user to catch the exception and handle as needed.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I wound up making this a one liner...         public static float WeightedAverage<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, float> value, Func<T, float> weight)
        {
            return items.Sum(item => value(item) * weight(item)) / items.Sum(weight);
        }

Comment: I had to add "If weightedSum.AlmostZero() return 0" after the calculations to protect against division by zero when all the weights and or all the values are zero. AlmostZero is an extension function checks if a double is zero.

Comment: Note that this enumerates the records twice. In many applications that's OK but if they're being streamed from a database or are otherwise impossible or expensive to re-enumerate, it'll break. Personally I type 'records' as IReadOnlyCollection<T> instead of IEnumerable<T> to indicate to the caller that it's their responsibility to handle this (e.g by calling .ToList() first if necessary).

Answer (score 4):

If you're certain that for each foreign key in Table2 there is a corresponding record in Table1, then you can avoid the join just making a group by.

In that case, the LINQ query is like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> wheighted_averages =
    from record in Table2
    where record.PCR != -1
    group record by record.ForeignKey into bucket
    select bucket.Sum(record => record.PCR * record.Length) / 
        bucket.Sum(record => record.Length);
```

**UPDATE**

This is how you can get the `wheighted_average` for a specific `foreign_key`.

```
IEnumerable<Record> records =
    (from record in Table2
    where record.ForeignKey == foreign_key
    where record.PCR != -1
    select record).ToList();
int wheighted_average = records.Sum(record => record.PCR * record.Length) /
    records.Sum(record => record.Length);
```

The ToList method called when fetching the records, is to avoid executing the query twice while aggregating the records in the two separate Sum operations.

Comment: This returns one value for each different ForeignKey. If you want only the wheighted average for a specific one and only ForeignKey, then you can avoid the GroupBy, and just filter the records with the desired foreign key, and perform the aggregation operations afterwards. I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Answer (score 2):

(Answering jsmith's comment to the answer above)

If you don't wish to cycle through some collection, you can try the following:

```
var filteredList = Table2.Where(x => x.PCR != -1)
 .Join(Table1, x => x.ForeignKey, y => y.Key, (x, y) => new { x.PCR, x.Length });

int weightedAvg = filteredList.Sum(x => x.PCR * x.Length) 
    / filteredList.Sum(x => x.Length);
```

Comment: Just so you know, my solution assumes that you wanted to calculate the weighted average over a set of rows whose foreign key matches the key value of any row in the first table.  Fede's solution will get you rows for a specific foreign key.  So, feel free to pick whichever solution is more appropriate.