# How to do this simple weighted average in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I'm just curious if this could be done in a single LINQ statement. I need to do a simple weighted average like this:

```
IEnumerable<double> values = { v0, v1, v2, v3, ...}
WeightedAverage = (((v0 + v1) / 2 + v2) / 2 + v3) / 2 ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted Average with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714639/weighted-average-with-linq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
double average = values.Aggregate((x, y) => (x + y) / 2.0);
```