# how one can calculate a weight average price after a group by?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the datatable below :

```
qty     price     date
5         2        1/25
6         1        1/25
8         3        4/25
1         2        4/25
```

and I want :

```
qty     price    date
11       1.45     1/25
9        2.88     4/25
```

I have already group the datatable by date with

```
 var groups = ToCalc.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field("trade_date"));
```

and the qty sum is like :

```
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                qty = Convert.ToDouble( group.Sum(r => r.Field("EXEC_QTY")));
            }
```

but I don't know how to calculate the weighted average price.
Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weighted Average with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714639/weighted-average-with-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
weightedAverage = group.Sum(r => r.Field("EXEC_QTY") * r.Field("price"))
     / group.Sum(r => r.Field("EXEC_QTY"));
```

Add Convert.ToDouble if you really need it.

Since you comment that qty is a double and price is a decimal:

```
weightedAverage = group.Sum(r => (decimal)r.Field("EXEC_QTY") * r.Field("price"))
     / group.Sum(r => (decimal)r.Field("EXEC_QTY"));
```

(Wouldn't it make more sense for price to be decimal and quantity to be a double?  Or for both to be decimal?)

Comment: thanks, i tried :             price =Convert.ToDouble( group.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("EXEC_QTY") * r.Field<decimal>("EXEC_PRICE"))
                    /group.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("EXEC_QTY")));  But EXEC_QTY is a decimal and EXEC_Price is a double , how to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Data
    {
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new Data[] { 
            new Data { Qty = 5, Price = 2, Date = "1/25"  },
            new Data { Qty = 6, Price = 1, Date = "1/25"  },
            new Data { Qty = 8, Price = 3, Date = "4/25"  },
            new Data { Qty = 1, Price = 2, Date = "4/25"  },
        };

        var weighted = data.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                           .Select(group => new Data { 
                               Date = group.Key, 
                               Qty = group.Sum(i => i.Qty), 
                               Price = group.Sum(i => i.Price * i.Qty) / group.Sum(i => i.Qty)
                       });            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var results = ToCalc.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field("trade_date"))
    .Select(grp => 
            {
                var quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field("EXEC_QTY"));
                var avg = grp.Sum(r => r.Field("EXEC_QTY") * r.Field("price")) / quantity;
                return new { 
                               TradeDate = grp.Key, 
                               Quantity = quantity, 
                               WeightedAverage = avg
                           };
            });
```

`results` would then be an enumerable of anonymous objects containing the information you want, it much more accessible structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform all grouping inside one method by using [this `Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx)overload:

```
var groups = ToCalc.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.date, (k, g) => new
    {
        date = k,
        qty = g.Sum(i => i.qty),
        price = g.Sum(i => i.qty * i.price) / g.Sum(i => i.qty)
    });
```

This will give you something like:

```
{ date = "1/25", qty = 11, price = 1.4545454545454546 }
{ date = "4/25", qty = 9, price = 2.8888888888888888 }
```